# .htaccess file showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\-uk\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\.domain\-uk\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\-uk\.net\/my\-integra" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^status\.domain\-uk\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.status\.domain\-uk\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\-uk\.net\/service\-status" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dd\.domain\-uk\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dd\.domain\-uk\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/sub\.domain\.co\.uk\/preauth\/0J9A7MT35N" [R=301,L]
```

the status. redirects but the two after are showing 500 Internal Server Error

above this i have the standard Wordpress code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Check your error log plus remove the quotes from your target url

Comment: check htaccess here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: i removed the quotes but im just getting 404 errors now

Answer (score 0):

The first rules that you want in your htaccess file are the ones the redirect the browser, the order is important, you don't want to redirect the browser after wordpress's internal rewriting. So first, you can clean up your redirect rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my\.domain\-uk\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain-uk.net/my-integra [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?status\.domain\-uk\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain-uk.net/service-status [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dd\.domain\-uk\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://sub.domain.co.uk/preauth/0J9A7MT35N [R=301,L]
```

The `?` makes the grouping optional, and the `NC` ignored the case. So **after** these rules, you can put your wordpress rules.

Comment: ok, ive just tired this code above my wordpress code and im still getting 500 error

Comment: Are you sure you have MOD_rewrite loaded?